# Responsive bullets with horizontal and vertical centered HTML content

Tags: html, css, css3

In my current project I develop a responsive site which has only on desktop a fixed width. Otherwise it's fluid. My client or rather my art director ;) want's fluid bullets with horizontal and vertical centered content on the site. To illustrate that I created a [dabblet](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/09a36d96c632db19dc80/44c424d60d3e7ec3c153f1480a98a70bb79853a3).

Here is my HTML for the bullet:

```html
<div class="ib">
  <div class="ib_ow">
    <div class="ib_iw">
      <div class="ib_c">Some text or markup</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS for the bullet looks so:

```css
.ib {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;

  border-radius: 50%;

  background: #f90;
}

.ib:hover {
  background: #790;
}

.ib_ow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.ib_iw {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.ib_c {
  display: table-cell;

  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Full code of my example you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/09a36d96c632db19dc80/44c424d60d3e7ec3c153f1480a98a70bb79853a3). And as a playground you can use this [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/09a36d96c632db19dc80).

It works fine, but is there a solution with less code? I've tried pseudo elements based on [this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) on css-tricks.com with no success. My problem is: I have no fixed width or height for the container. The bullet should use all available spaces.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Very descriptive first post. +1. I hope you get some fine answers.

Comment: Seems a little over complicated but not bad. I'll take a look in the morning and see if its plausible to reduce the styles, that many elements in the Dom seems excessive.